# OPENROWSET BCP Bulk Import OUTPUT clause works on dev system SQL Server 2016 but fails on SQL Server 2014 in production

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I think my problem here is just SQL Server versions, but I still need a work around or a fix. What I am doing is pretty simple.

I have a bulk import using `OPENROWSET` that populates a temp table (staging table) and this temp table is set up by doing a:

```
select top 0 * 
into ##Person 
from tbl_Person
```

against an existing physical table to get its column structure. That works fine. This brings in the primary key field (named ID) which is NOT an index field.

I then populate `##Person` by doing an `OPENROWSET` query against a `.csv` file with a BCP format file (XML). This works also. The next step does a MERGE to move the newly acquired data (in the staging table) into the original physical table.

Then I use the OUTPUT clause from the MERGE statement to insert the new ID values in the tbl_Person physical table into another physical table as foreign key values. Here is where the problem occurs. On my dev system running VS 2017 and SQL Server 2016 developer edition, the whole thing works nicely. However, on the production server (SQL Server 2014 Express) I get (you probably guessed):

[image]

I would like to get it to work on SQL Server 2014 without having to rewrite the whole thing. Perhaps if I alter the OUTPUT clause, or set INSERT OFF at the right point. I have tried actually deleting the ID primary key (NOT an index) from the `##Person` temp table, but to no avail.

Here is the truncated code:

```
USE [thedb]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_BulkMergeDynamic] 
     @OrganisationID int, @DF nvarchar(1024), @FF nvarchar(1024)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Person') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##Person

    --SET IDENTITY_INSERT ##Person OFF - Requires table creation then alter table, which might be the solution
    select top 0 * into ##Person from tbl_Person 
    --GO 
    ALTER TABLE ##Person NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all 
    ALTER TABLE ##Person ALTER COLUMN DateCreated DateTime NULL 

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ##Person (tpp.RecordTitle, tpp.SecurityCode, ... truncated
SELECT CONCAT(tpp.FirstName, '' '', tpp.LastName), tpp.SecurityCode, ...truncated
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK''' + @DF + ''', FORMATFILE=''' + @FF + ''' ) tpp'

ALTER TABLE ##Person CHECK CONSTRAINT all

     EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

    -- SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_Person ON
    --ALTER TABLE tbl_Person ALTER COLUMN DateCreated DateTime NULL
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_Person OFF
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_OC OFF
    alter table ##Person drop column ID
    MERGE INTO tbl_Person AS tgt USING ##Person AS src
       ON tgt.EmailAddress1=src.EmailAddress1

    WHEN NOT MATCHED then 
    insert values(src.RecordTitle, src.SecurityCode, GETDATE(), src.FK_User_CreatedBy, ... truncated)
    --SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_Person OFF
           --VVVVVVVVV The problem seems to be here in SQL Server 2104 only. SQL Server 2016 developer executes with the right results in output tables.
    OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.EmailAddress1, @OrID, 1 INTO tbl_OC(FK_Person, RecordTitle, FK_Or, IsrID);-- output inserted.*; --@PersonTempID;

    drop table ##Person
END

GO
```

Comment: Question: is the `merge` statement in your question the full SQL statement, or are there additional clauses in your real script? I'm seeing nothing in there that warrants the use of the `merge` statement. A simple `insert into tbl_person(...) select ... from ##person AS pt where not exists(select 1 from tbl_person AS p where p.EmailAddress1=pt.EmailAddress1)`. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Merge is supposed to be the more succinct and flexible alternative, according to the Microsoft documentation, but I could try the insert approach provided it manipulates the primary key field appropriately. The merge allows me to track and update the primary key from the import and to avoid duplicates using the match statement. Thus I would like to know how to solve the specific problem that occurs with the merge output and the ID insert. It's not the full statement - per the truncates - for brevity and because of intellectual property - but you couldn't run it without data anyway.

Comment: Sure, SQL-merge is flexible in the situations where you can only do those things with a merge statement. I.e. where you have one or more `WHERE [NOT] MATCHED` clauses. If you only have one of such clauses, IMO it is preferrable to stick to the basic insert/update/delete statements. Because in that case you aren't merging in the true spirit of the statement. You're then only just inserting, updating or deleting.

Comment: Okay. That's great TT and thanks and I might try it for the purposes of testing. 

Meanwhile - per the actual question - does someone know how to actually solve/answer the problem/question re. the merge statement? One reason for keeping the merge is that I have to extend it in exactly as suggested for more matched clauses and for further output statements (including with nesting and dynamic SQL exec calls), and so I need to know how to make the statement work for SQL 2014 as it does for SQL 2016.

Does anyone actually know how to fix the MERGE for SQL Server 2014?

Comment: I am getting quasi stable results from this on both my Dev server and production box now. All the SQL Server are set to 2008 compaitbility = 100 . With insert as suggested I get the exact same script passing muster about 70 % of the time. If I script a create from the existing installed SP which is working and running, then I cannot recreate it! I get the ID/INSERT ON column list error. Weird! If it does install as an SP (CREATE works) with no changes then it runs fine! ???

Comment: If you are not getting a satisfactory answer, or any answer at all, I would suggest moving this question to dba.stackexchange.com. There you will have more db experts that can take a look at your question. If you do post your question there, it would be a good idea to reference this question here or better yet delete the question here (cross-posting is frowned upon).

Comment: A couple thoughts:  why use a global temp table ## instead of a local one #?  Also, I think you need a new session after identity_insert change... Maybe you can put those lines into dynamic sql and run them and it will work more properly.  exec(' SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_Person ON') then turn it back off after executing.

Comment: Just a though: do you have more than one schema in your database? Check that all of you SPs and tables have only one schema version. What I am trying to say is check that your sp and tables are unique.